# Quando eu clico no ListView pra abrir outra Aciticity o app trava e fexa

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-activity, arraylist

Eu estou criando um App que procure redes wifi proximas e depois consiga se conectar a eles, mas travei no inicio, pois consigo fazer ele scannear, mas quando eu clico em alguma rede da lista, o que me redirecionaria para outra Acitiviry, o app trava e fexa, por que isso?
**MainAcitivity.java**

```
package com.emanuel.testes;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button buttonScan;
    private List<ScanResult> results;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private boolean f = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonScan = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                scanWifi();
            }
        });

        listView = findViewById(R.id.wifiList);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi está desativado. Eu vou ativa-lo por você.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        scanWifi();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Element.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                f = true;
            }

        });
        if(f) {
            this.finish();
        }
    }


    private void scanWifi() {
        arrayList.clear();
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Procurando ESPs...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            unregisterReceiver(this);

            for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
                arrayList.add(scanResult.SSID);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Element.java**

```
package com.emanuel.testes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Element extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="@string/procurar_esps"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wifiList" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wifiList"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="439dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scanBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="FUNCIONA POR FAVOR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Você declarou sua Activity Element no manisfest?

Answer (score 0):

Vc deve incluir a sua nova "activity" no arquivo "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.Sua_Activity"></activity>

</application>
```